# What encryption does vim -x use?

Tags: security, vim, encryption

I read `man vim`, `:h -x` and `:h encryption` none of this actually says what algorithm it's encrypted with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`:h 'cryptmethod'` says that PkZip and Blowfish (new in Vim 7.3) are possible encryption methods.  A look around `FEAT_CRYPT` in [vim/src/misc2.c](http://code.google.com/p/vim/source/browse/src/misc2.c) confirms it.

The weak encryption method is documented in [PKWARE's zip file format documentation](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT), and the new strong encryption is documented on [Bruce Schneier's Blowfish page](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish.html).

Answer (score 6):

I know that they added support for blowfish encryption in 7.3. Other than that it's zip.

If you're using 7.3 go:

```
:set cryptmethod?
```

to see what method you're using.

Comment: apparently `:set cryptmethod` isn't an option before 7.3